# How to render a content inside directive at various places

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I want a component directive to render anything put inside it's selector to be rendered at specific sections inside its html.

**header, footer, main** in this case.

any.html

```
<any-selector>
    <div>content to place</div>
</any-selector>
```

Expecting it to render following

any-selector.html

```
<header><div>content to place</div></header>
<main><div>content to place</div></main>
<footer><div>content to place</div></footer>
```

tried it with `ng-content` but it rendered only at first occurrence of `<ng-content>`

If there's any way to achieve this?

Comment: What was the implementation of `ng-content` you have tried? Can you share the implementation instead of just snippets? Or better yet create a fiddle?

Comment: @Ajeet : Did u try my answer ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek  Yeah man, it worked like heaven, Only change I did was to use `outerHTML` insted of `innerHTML`.Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is an expected behavior from `ng-content`, either you put `[select]` to point to certain `ng-content` or you can render just on the first occurrence of `ng-content`.

I tried a way which has worked for me. [Here is the demo working code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-content-projection-tladvz?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)

```
<any-selector>
    <div #myProjection>content to place</div>
</any-selector>
```

and then in **app-selector.HTML** you can do :

```
<div id='border'>
    <h1>Hello Component</h1>
    <header><div #canvas></div></header>
    <footer><div #canvas></div></footer>
</div>
```

**app-selector.component**

```
  @ViewChildren("canvas") canvas: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  @ContentChild("myProjection") str : ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.canvas.forEach((div: ElementRef) => 
         div.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.str.nativeElement.innerHTML));
   }
```