# Accessing child Components inside the parent component's html element

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

The requirement that I am having is to generate a component that can access and render the child components that are added to it in the markup.

**HTML**

```
<my-parent>
    <span>hey</span>
    <span>heck</span>
</my-parent>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<div>
    <span>before</span>
    <span>hey</span>
    <span>after</span>
    <br />
    <span>before</span>
    <span>heck</span>
    <span>after</span>
</div>
```

I was not able to find any resource to help me with it. This is a behavior similar to how mat select interacts with mat options.

Comment: The Angular source code is freely available - have you looked at the source code for mat select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-content` with `select` as [demoed here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rtkbp7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

```
<my-parent>
  <span a>hey</span>
    <span b>heck</span>
</my-parent>
```

```
  <div>
    <span>before - </span>
    <ng-content select="[b]"></ng-content>
    <span> - after</span>
    <br />
    <span>before - </span>
    <ng-content select="[a]"></ng-content>
    <span> - after</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what if I had spans in a ngfor.

Comment: @SachithRukshan : I also has this question for which I even put bounty. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988436/why-ng-content-selector-is-not-working-inside-ngfor . Let me know if it helped

Comment: @SachithRukshan : Here is another link which I answered for something somewhat similar . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60761677/how-to-render-a-content-inside-directive-at-various-places/60762239#60762239